# Create new node which is the parent of the document

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I am using C to parse XML with libxml2.

I am creating a new node `xmlNewTextChild()`

```
cur = xmlDocGetRootElement( doc );
tvNode = xmlNewTextChild( cur, NULL, "tv", NULL );
```

I am wondering how I can create this node but without having it be a child to a parent node, so the new node is the root element basically.

Thanks

Comment: The root _element_ of an XML document cannot be a text _node_

Comment: @SeanBright Let me rephrase, I want to create a new node which does not have a parent node? is this possible?

Comment: A text node? Use [`xmlNewText`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNewText)?

Comment: @SeanBright what will the first param be in this function, it is meant to be the nodes parent

Comment: Read the documentation at the link I sent

Comment: `xmlNewNode` with no parent will create a root node

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new node

   ```c
   xmlNodePtr new_root = xmlNewNode(NULL, BAD_CAST "your_root_name");
   ```
2. Set it as the root element

   ```c
   xmlNodePtr old_root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
   xmlUnlinkNode(old_root);
   xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, new_root);
   ```
3. Attach the previous document’s root node as a child to the new root:

   ```c
   xmlAddChild(new_root, old_root);
   ```